# Little colored lines on my laptop screen

Tags: display, lcd, laptop-repair, laptop-display

My LCD screen has three noticeable problems. Note that when I plug an external LCD tv into my laptop, the picture that the LCD TV displays the screen is fine.

As seen in: http://ubuntuone.com/5Mf2cNq14NeprqlcRG1Pce

The first and most noticeable and frequent problem is white lines that go horizontally along the LCD screen. When I touch the monitor or adjust the angle, some of the white lines appear while other white lines disappear or flicker.

Here is a picture:
http://ubuntuone.com/6jqkeHiRnAwijI8LJLPfuL

The second problem, much smaller, is the little colored lines, usually just one or two, that go up and down the screen. You can see one vertical blue line in the picture. The last thing is a glowing, rectangle-with-rounded-edges shaped halo that sometimes appears on the screen with the white lines.

The halo looks like this: http://ubuntuone.com/44rfw1scomcHl0aOZdxpV6

The middle 1/3 of the glowing halo is missing, but as you can see, the entire halo would block pretty much the entire screen. It usually appears to be shining forth from behind the white lines. Last thing: replacing the display cable that connects the LCD to the motherboard made absolutely no difference. Same screen problems before and after I replaced the cable. That's all.

So, do you know what's up with my hp dv4-2170us laptop?

Comment: Please don't ask people to go away to get the question! Please take the time to put your question here, including any relevant pictures! -1 I have made the changes you want though

Comment: Did all these problems start at the same time ? I currently have the "little colored lines" problem with my laptop...

Comment: You also have an answer on Yahoo Answers! http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130814071926AAUOtpF

Comment: @David - Thanks for editing the question (and answering it twice) for me - I couldn't do it conveniently from my smartphone and my laptop was being a pain.

Comment: None of the links in the question work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At this point, the wires that connect directly to the pixels from the cable are probably shorted or separated. There is nothing you can do about this now, but you can buy a new screen for a very low price on eBay, and they are very easy to replace.

[Source -  Your question on Yahoo answers!](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130814071926AAUOtpF)

Answer (score 0):

The failure may be a bad connection anywhere between the output of your graphics processor and the screen itself. Most commonly, it's the flat cable connecting the screen to the output socket on the mainboard. 
This cable is stressed every time you open and close the lid of your laptop and may eventually break.

If the anomalies change when you move the lid, then it is most likely the cable. If they stay the same or only change when you move/shake the whole laptop, it may also be the connectors on either the mainboard or the screen. If they change when you apply (soft) pressure to the screen itself (especially at the edges) it may also be the screen itself.

Changing just the cable is much cheaper than changing the whole screen, but availability varies between manufacturers and models. For some models, the cable will be fixed to the screen and can only be swapped by replacing the whole screen. for some, the screen will only be available fully assembled in the lid. For most, you won't even find any parts officially on sale. But you can always try to get a used/disfunct one off ebay and salvage the parts.

Replacing the whole lid is moderately easy if you have the right tools. Replacing the cable or inserting a new screen in the lid may be way more complicated depending on your model.

Comment: I tried changing the display cable, but just in case, I'll try opening it up and re-fastening the display cable to the motherboard.

Comment: Refastening the display cable to the motherboard didn't make a difference. Neither did loosening the tension on the display cable, where the cable goes around the left hinge of the monitor.

Comment: Now, tugging at the display cable of the disassembled laptop produced some interesting patterns, including the halo pattern, but also some weird discoloration and blacking out half of the screen. It didn't produce the typical horizontal white lines, though. See weird halo... http://ubuntuone.com/1SOzrfTWadxaBb1Y52VcQR ... And discoloration... http://ubuntuone.com/6HZ92BNMrngfwTXf71ThK0

Comment: You tugged _away_ from the screen? Can you lift the screen from the lid? Is there a connector to the screen or is the cable directly soldered to the backside of the screen? You have a last chance of it being just the cable or the connector to the display, but I doubt it. Start searching for a replacement.

Comment: I separated the lcd from the plastic lid. Nothing was soldered, but the connections were fine.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't happen to know how to find the hinge dim switch? It keeps getting accidentally hit, but I don't see that hinge switch anywhere.

Comment: If you can see a small plastic tip dipping into a small hole near the hinges when closing the lid, this may be a mechanical or optical switch. But most laptops use a magnetic switch located at the outer rim of the lid. Just use a small screwdriver to find the magnetic spot. On one side you will find the small magnet, on the other side a small magnetic-flux sensor (called a Hall-sensor) mostly in the form of a tiny black plastic chip on the main board or a separate small board (maybe also containing microphones, antennas or light sensors).